# Calling class-specific method from another class

Tags: python, function, class

I am working in a class called AlgoSystem, which is given strategy_0 and strategy_1 as inputs under initialization as well as the number of strategies (2 in this case). The strategy classes are stored in a dictionary called "strategies" within the AlgoSystem. Both strategy_0 and strategy_1 are **different** classes themselves, but both with a function called "__on_tick". These functions I want to call from within the AlgoSystem class. 
My current attempt to do this is seen below:

```
class AlgoSystem:

    def __init__(self, strategy_0, strategy_1, numstrategies):
        self.var= 1
        self.strategies = {0 : strategy_0,
                           1 : strategy_1}
        self.num_strategies = numstrategies

    def start(self):
         for i in range(self.num_strategies):
             self.strategies[i].__on_tick(self.var)

class Strategy_zero:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def __on_tick(self, var):
        self.x = self.x + var
        print(self.x)

class Strategy_one:
    def __init__(self, y):
        self.y = y

    def __on_tick(self, var):
        self.y = self.y - var
        print(self.y)



strategy_0 = Strategy_zero(2)
strategy_1 = Strategy_one(4)

num_strategies = 2

system = AlgoSystem(strategy_0, strategy_1, 2)
system.start()
```

When I run the code above, I am given the error:

```
Strategy_zero' object has no attribute '_AlgoSystem__on_tick'
```

Apparently I'm not calling the class-functions "__on_tick" properly. How should I do this? I need to do it in a way, so I keep track on the changes of the two sub-classes (strategy_0 and strategy_1) through my defined dictionary within AlgoSystem: "strategies".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The double underscore prefix is specifically designed to prevent you from doing exactly what you are doing.

There is no reason for you to use it here. Remove the prefix and can your methods just `on_tick`.

Answer (score 1):

Double underscore names are hidden names (hidden by obfuscation).   I suggest having your on_tick method be called on_tick and try again.

Answer (score 0):

The following code might help clarify what's going on with name-mangling.

```
class A:
    def __mangled(self):
        print "Class A name-mangled method"

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        a = A()

        try:
            a.__mangled()
        except AttributeError:
            # an attempt to access a name-mangled method assumes that
            # the '_{class_name}' prefix should use 'B' as the class name
            print "A instance has no attribute '_B__mangled'"

        a._A__mangled() 
        # prints "Class A name-mangled method"

        getattr(a, '_{}__mangled'.format(a.__class__.__name__))()
        # same thing, but can be done without knowing the class name

B()
```

So, you could update `self.strategies[i].__on_tick(self.var)` to be:

```
strat = self.strategies[i]
getattr(strat, '_{}__on_tick'.format(strat.__class__.__name__)(self.var)
```

But, it would probably be best to not precede `__on_tick` with a double-underscore since it is intended to be accessed outside the class/instance.